# Bioacoustics nomenclature for sound communication (inter/intra-species, receiver/emitter benefit)

Tags: nomenclature

In the field of chemical ecology, [semiochemicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiochemical) refer to the chemicals released and detect by organisms to communicate between each other. They are classified as:

- [pheromones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pheromone): released and received by members of the same species (e.g. mating pheromones)
- [allomones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allomone): released by one species that affects the behavior of another species to the benefit of the originator but not the receiver (e.g. repellent odor to avoid being eaten)
- [kairomones:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kairomone) released by one species that affects the behavior of another species to the benefit of the receiver but not the originator (e.g. predator's odor)
- [synomones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiochemical#Synomone): beneficial to both emitter and receiver (e.g. organism warning a predator about its toxicity)

I find this classification very helpful and one can easily see similarities in sound communication. Has anybody heard about a similar nomenclature for sounds?

Answer (score 4):

In my experience the terms conspecific and heterospecific are typically what is used when talking about vocal communication, though this does not say anything about intentionality/receiver necessarily. Heterospecific recognition is used to describe situations in which one species understands a call from another species (most common with different species recognizing each others' alarm calls).